# Generating HTML tables in NodeJS-served pages from MySQL data

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, pug

I would like to update tables in my existing HTML pages dynamically using data retrieved from a MySQL databases. These pages are being served by NodeJS. Unfortunately, I don't have a very good idea of where to start on something like this, short of using a templating engine like Jade. Would anyone be able to link me to an example of something like this, or otherwise advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can read data from a MySql database and then stream those data via websocket to many client connected on the same page.

First of all you must install the modules needed for this example.

This node js module is needed to read a MySQL database
**$ npm install mysql@2.0.0-alpha9**

And then Socket.io to deal with the HTML5 websocket
**$ npm install socket.io**

follow this tutorial for more details.
http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/

The first part of our code is needed to set up the connection with database and to load the html ( client.hmtl ) page in which we are going to print the data fetched with our MySql queries in your HTML tables.